# Eclipse how print missing libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

I have many missing libraries in a Java Eclipse (3.7.2) project. Is there any way of copying the list of libraries, to paste into a document for editing?

Comment: it's impossible to tell what libraries are missing, but you should be able to look in the 'Problems' tab in Eclipse, and see what classes are not found.  Then you can google to find which jars are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the errors in the "Problems View" and copy them. Eclipse will put a pure-text version into your clipboard which you can then paste into an Editor.

If you have a working project and want to copy libraries from there, open the (hidden) `.classpath` file. It's XML which you can copy&paste. I haven't tried copy&paste from the "Build Path" dialog but maybe that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

While Eclipse may recognizes compile-time required dependencies that are missing i hardly doubt it knows runtime-required librarys (so no, eclipse and as faar as i know any other IDE does not support that unless dependency management is set up with for example Maven).

The librarys missed at compile time should show in the 'Problems' view of Eclipse.

```
Window -> Show View -> "Problems" (select view 'Problems')
```

Once you have a tab with that view you can order the problems by its description and all of the 'missing library..." issues will be listed in a group. You will then be able to select according entrys and CTRL+C / CTRL+V them out of there.

Also note that in my case using maven eclipse oftenly thinks there are classes or dependencys missing by the fact eclipse is not that skilled when it comes to local synchronization of your workspace.

Id rather invest that time to start adding missing dependencys or think about Maven for more proffessional dependency management.